# android: Headset plug listener

Tags: android

```
public class HeadsetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String TAG = "HeadSet";

    public HeadsetIntentReceiver() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch(state) {
                case(0):
                    Log.d(TAG, "Headset unplugged");
                    break;
                case(1):
                    Log.d(TAG, "Headset plugged");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code for listening for headphone plug, I initiated this from a `Service` class, but every time I plug and unplug it, nothing appears on the Logcat, any ideas?

AndriodManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.jason.automator.HeadphoneJackListenerService" />
        <receiver android:name=".HeadsetIntentReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your Manifest?

Comment: try registering your receiver dynamically rather than in manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't registered your receiver in manifest you can do like below

```
<receiver android:name=".HeadsetIntentReceiver" > 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Also you can register it dynamically.

When OS send this "HEADSET_PLUG" intent, OS set the flag "Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY" . That's why may be your code not working. So try registering dynamically like below in Activity or Service class instead of "AndroidManifest" things.

So try below code,

```
    IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    HeadsetIntentReceiver receiver = new HeadsetIntentReceiver();
    registerReceiver( receiver, receiverFilter );
```

Comment: I did add such lines to the manifest as the my edit above, but I think there's no such permission? It still produces no output

Comment: Thanks @Shirish Herwade <3. Finally it works, thank you so much

Comment: There is no such permission `android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`

Comment: In the manifest, it's supposed to be: 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>
But the manifest method doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Yes, via adding in manifest it is not working in my case as well. But with dynamic registration it is working fine

Answer (score 4):

If the minimum SDK version of your application is `LOLLIPOP`, it is recommended to refer to the `AudioManager` constant `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` in your receiver registration code instead.